# .htaccess redirect with multi-subdomain

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I'm currently using this rule to redirect traffic (except one url) to a new url.
It works fine when using a non www url like "subdomain.olddomain.com" but when accessing it with www like "www.subdomain.olddomain.com", I get a redirection error. This is the rule i use:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/exception($|/)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.newdomain.com/ [R=301,L]
```

What am I missing here? I'm not an expert in any way with htaccess… Thank you!
PS: I already searched for answeres but couldn't find any matching my subdomain issue.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like I had to change some domain settings, the rule above works as expected.